# Generate axml in new activity when I tap button

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-xml

I need to insert an `axml` block into a new activity.

**Code of activity axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="158.5dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
        android:background="@drawable/header1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="81.8dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
            android:background="@drawable/s2">
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/menuButton"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="78.9dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_marginTop="16.3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11.6dp" />
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/logo_murakami"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/logoButton"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4.6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="63.5dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_marginTop="6.0dp"
                android:clickable="true" />
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/cart"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cartButton"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_marginTop="16.3dp"
                android:clickable="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="79.2dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout9"
            android:background="#99000000">
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/cart2"
                android:layout_width="45.4dp"
                android:layout_height="47.9dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_marginTop="18.0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8.5dp" />
            <TextView
                android:text="КОШИК"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="296.4dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingBottom="24dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8.4dp"
                android:textSize="23sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="390.3dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:background="@drawable/middle1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout12">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="147.6dp"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout13">
                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/sushi"
                    android:layout_width="123.1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/image1"
                    android:background="#000" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:minWidth="25px"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:layout_width="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout14"
                    android:background="#cf8632" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:minWidth="25px"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:layout_width="184.9dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout15">
                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:layout_width="181.9dp"
                        android:layout_height="63.3dp"
                        android:id="@+id/posttittle"
                        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="7.7dp"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:minWidth="25px"
                        android:minHeight="25px"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="93.8dp"
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout16">
                        <TextView
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="48.7dp"
                            android:id="@+id/price"
                            android:layout_marginTop="39.8dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5.5dp"
                            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
                        <TextView
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:layout_width="58.8dp"
                            android:layout_height="53.3dp"
                            android:id="@+id/weight"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="21.5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="41.9dp"
                            android:textColor="#faaf56"
                            android:paddingTop="7dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout23"
                android:background="#99999999" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="68.6dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout10">
        <Button
            android:text="ОЧИСТИТИ КОШИК"
            android:layout_width="180.8dp"
            android:layout_height="68.6dp"
            android:id="@+id/ochistitiButton"
            android:background="#747271"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <Button
            android:text="ОФОРМИТИ"
            android:layout_width="180.8dp"
            android:layout_height="69.3dp"
            android:id="@+id/oformitButton"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:background="#c98f4a"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Axml code of product block.

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="147.6dp"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout13">
                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/sushi"
                    android:layout_width="123.1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/image1"
                    android:background="#000" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:minWidth="25px"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:layout_width="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout14"
                    android:background="#cf8632" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:minWidth="25px"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:layout_width="184.9dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout15">
                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:layout_width="181.9dp"
                        android:layout_height="63.3dp"
                        android:id="@+id/posttittle"
                        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="7.7dp"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:minWidth="25px"
                        android:minHeight="25px"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="93.8dp"
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout16">
                        <TextView
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="48.7dp"
                            android:id="@+id/price"
                            android:layout_marginTop="39.8dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5.5dp"
                            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
                        <TextView
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:layout_width="58.8dp"
                            android:layout_height="53.3dp"
                            android:id="@+id/weight"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="21.5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="41.9dp"
                            android:textColor="#faaf56"
                            android:paddingTop="7dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

How I can insert this block programatically into a new activity by tapping a button?

Comment: I don't get your point: Do you want to add a block of `axml` code everytime you add a new activity to your project? Or do you want to dynamically change the `axml` code during runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the xml of the product block in the layout of the activity, and leave it hidden (GONE) until you press the button.

```
 ...
 <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="147.6dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout13"
            android:visibility="GONE">
 ...
```

Then on the button click:

```
 findViewById(R.id.<button_id_here>).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v){
     findViewById(R.id.linearLayout13).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
 });
```

I'm doing this on the fly, so there could be any mistake :)

Comment: Okay, I will try this

Comment: If I have button on other activity, not in activity with hidden block?

Comment: You can create a method in this activity that performs the visibility change, and call this method from the other activity. You can do this by creating an interface or passing a reference of this activity to the other.

Comment: Can I set it visible, when I pass attributes between activities?

Comment: Yes, you can pass parameters to the method in the activity, from the other activity. If you need to, depending on the value of those parameters you can set the visibility GONE or VISIBLE (to hide/show it).

Comment: If you find this useful, mark it as the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could inflate this xml into a variable and add it to the view hierarchy:

```
RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.item);
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.product_block, null);
item.addView(child);
```